# Do while loop with single equal sign in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to code the following JS in coffeescript:

```
x = 0;
if(node.offsetParent) {
  do {
    x += node.offsetLeft;
  } while(node = node.offsetParent);
}
```

Here's what i have so far, but the node seems to come back null

```
if node.offsetParent
  loop
    x += node.offsetLeft
    break if typeof (node = node.offsetParent) == "undefined"
x
```

Comment: Your code looks correct.

Comment: Sorry, should of said the node variable comes back null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that when a DOM element `node` has no offset parent, `node.offsetParent` is `null`, not `undefined`. And `typeof null` is `'object'`, not `'undefined'`.

Why not take the same approach as the original JS loop, which simply checked `node.offsetParent` for falsy-ness? Then your code might look something like:

```
x = 0
if node.offsetParent
  loop
    x += node.offsetLeft
    break unless (node = node.offsetParent)
x
```

I'd also like to point out that while CoffeeScript has no `do..while` syntax, you can simply use a `while` loop in this case, making your `if` superfluous:

```
x = 0
while node.offsetParent
  x += node.offsetLeft
  node = node.offsetParent
x
```